# How can I respond to a curl request from a node express service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I recently discovered the `curl wttr.in/London` command, which returns a response inside the terminal.

I was wondering what I'd need to do to get something like this to work on a node/express endpoint i.e. what will the response I need to send look like?

I'm looking for resources to understand curl and how it works better I suppose, and don't know what to google for.

Here's an example response I'd like to send back:

```
Temperature: 10C
Max: 12
Min: 8
Humidity: 66%
```

Comment: curl makes an HTTP request to a web server, those usually reply with HTML documents or files, but they can send back arbitrary responses. To get a plain text response, just send back plain text.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks, I'm testing this out right now using just a `res.send()` method with strings in.

Comment: @ChrisG Here's what I get when I send back `Temperature: 11C`: 

`Temperature: 11C%`

How do I avoid the trailing `%` symbol?

Comment: The issue with the trailing `%` can be solved by adding a new line character `\n` 

Here's an example of a response that works: 

`res.send('Temperature: 11C\nMax: 12\nMin: 8\nHumidity: 60%\nDescription: Cloudy\n');`